# Asp.Net Identity FrameWork sample ERRORS and loosing Extension Methods in project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, extension-methods

First thing that I must say is "Sorry About My Bad English"

Recently I'm trying to learn and download asp.net Identity Framework and its sample from this sources:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.0.0
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples

I downloaded the sample from package manager console in an Empty mvc 5 project (using VS 2013) and after the ending of downloads, i opened /Home/Index.cshtml. after a few second VS listed a some errors in error list. At next i tried to see another view and after it VS listed some other errors. Again and again. After opening each View. Here is some of them:

The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context    c:...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Views\Home\Index.cshtml

'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Users...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Views\Home\Index.cshtml

These errors appears for each Extension Methods in all Views. In the intellisense list there is no Extension Method. I've lost all them in the project. I searched many forums and programing mvc sites but no suitable answer were found.

please help me.

Comment: I found that issues & errors are related with ~/views/web.config.
But I've got no idea that which changes make these errors. I created new project and download identity sample without changing ~/views/web.config, but no changes in this file disrupt identity framework.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.
I change .Net framework version from 4.5.1 to 4.5 in solution's properties and rebuild solution.
Then again I change .Net framework version from 4.5 to 4.5.1. After it Visual Studio recognize all extension methods.
I can't understand how it solve my issue but it worked.
Sorry about my bad English.